# Error json serialization keyNotFound(CodingKeys... - when I am using Wi-Fi or VPN Connection

Tags: json, swift, serialization, wifi, vpn

I have a function that is to get data from Server but sometimes when the application does request through a Wifi or a VPN I obtain . Why it happens when the application does request through wifi or VPN?

Error:

```
Error json serialization keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "host", intValue: nil),
 Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "recommendations", intValue:
 nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 2", intValue: 2), CodingKeys(stringValue: "blockedHosts",
 intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 1", intValue: 1)], debugDescription: "No value 
associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"host\", intValue: nil) (\"host\").", 
underlyingError: nil))
```

Model:

```
class ListOfPlayers: Decodable {
    let players: [Player]
    let recommendations: [Recommendations]
    let proxies: [Proxies]
    let preloadAdStartPageUrl: String
}

class Recommendations: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let url: String
    let title: String
    let color: String
    let image: String?
    let blockedHosts: [BlockedHostsRecommendation]
}

class BlockedHostsRecommendation: Decodable {
    let host: String
    let countries: [String]
}
```

I repeat, the application works well, but sometimes I catch this error only through Wifi or VPN.

Comment: When it fails, print the JSON. `do { try JSONDecoder...} catch { print("JSON Decoding failed: \(error) with: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))"}` and check why exactly. Some value might be optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest capturing network traffic with a proxy like Charles and analyze the received data. The error message shows that `JSONDecoder` can't decode `BlockedHostsRecommendation.host`, it can be possible that in some cases you backend doesn't provide that field

Comment: You are right, it is a problem with the backend. I did examine the backend JSON file and find the problem with some rows.